# Why Angular Material modal dialog expand if there is text inside span?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

I have html like this

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Reject" ng-cloak="">
  <form name="rejectionForm">
    <md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-dialog-content">
        <h2 class="md-title">Reject confirmation for</h2>
        <span ng-bind-html="vm.parent.task.label"></span>
        <textarea placeholder="Please provide a reason for rejection" style="width: 530px; height: 75px"></textarea>
      </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <span flex="flex"></span>
      <md-button ng-click="vm.parent.cancel()">CANCEL</md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="vm.parent.reject()" class="md-primary md-raised">REJECT</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

and modal dialog is expanded to 1032px. It work when I change span to div (or if I set display to block), I can use div but I want to know why the modal dialog is expanded if there is span with text.

Comment: Without knowing what is vm.parent.task.label, it would be difficult to understand why. My gut feeling is that there is an unclosed tag in the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, it seems to be the combination of the `textarea` *after* the span which is causing the problem, not the `span` itself, which can be observed by removing the `textarea` - the `span` behaves like a `div`.

Adding `display:block` to the `textarea` solves the problem - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/ZOmPLp?editors=1010#0)

```
<span>wqweqweqweqweqweqweqw eqweqwe qweqweqweqweqweq weqweqweqwe qweqwe </span>
<div>
    <textarea placeholder="Please provide a reason for rejection" style="width: 530px; height: 75px; display:block"></textarea>
</div>
```